# Webkit border-radius background misbehavior

Tags: webkit, css

If I remove the border-radius property, Chrome displays the whole background in gray. When I add border-radius, the page background turns white. This is only Chrome/webkit specific. The page works fine with gray background everywhere in Firefox/Opera/IE. Any ideas why?

http://devio.us/~hara/test.html

Comment: Assigning styles such as 'width' to the html element is generally not a good idea. Instead apply them to the body element or best a wrapper div

Comment: Thanks a lot! Applying a wrapper or using the body element fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. @Zlatev is definitely right, you should probably your styles to a `<div>` within the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

I tried playing around with it, and I found that if you put the background on the `<body>` tag it still overflows to fill the entire page, however if you specify the background for the `<body>` tag and then declare the `<html>` tag to have a different background (say, white), it look like you were hoping it would.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="faviconNoFap.ico" />
<style type="text/css">
html {
    background: white;
}
body {
    width: 760px;
    margin: 55px auto 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px;
    font-family: Hoefler;
    background: #e4e4e4;

}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>
<title>Test title of a test web-page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Heading Heading Heading Heading</h2>

<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>


<h2>Heading Heading Heading Heading</h2>

<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text.</p>



</body>
</html>
```